# What is wrong with this code for creating lists in OCaml?

Tags: function, random, functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to create a program in OCaml [randlist len max], which would generate an int list of length len with integers smaller than max.

I am wondering what is wrong with the following code:

```
let randlist dolzina maksimum =
  let rec aux dolz maks acc =
    match (List.length acc) with
    | dolz -> acc
    | _ -> aux dolz maks ((Random.int maks) :: acc)
  in
  aux dolzina maksimum []
```

This always returns an empty list and I do not understand why.

Another thing that confuses me is what goes wrong with the following code:

```
let randlist dolzina maksimum =
  Random.self_init ()
  let rec aux dolz maks acc =
    match (List.length acc) with
    | dolz -> acc
    | _ -> aux dolz maks ((Random.int maks) :: acc)
  in
  aux dolzina maksimum []
```

As soon as I add the Random.self init () the whole code crashes. What exactly does Random.self_init do, when and how do I use it?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `List.init`?

Comment: `List.length` is O(n), and if you're calling on each recursive iteration, you're looking at very poor runtime efficiency.

Comment: Your second example is missing a `;` after `Random.self_init ()`. Without that you have a syntax error. This is not what I'd typically describe as a "crash" but rather a compilation failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern matching deconstructs values that match a pattern into smaller parts, it doesn't test equality. In other words, your first case

```ml
match List.length acc with
| dolz -> acc
```

reads: take the value returned by `List.length acc`, name it `dolz` in the right hand side of the arrow `->`, and run the code after `->`. Notice that this means that `dolz` matches any values.
This is why the compiler warns you that the second case

```
| _ -> aux dolz maks ((Random.int maks) :: acc)
```

is never used.

For your second question, the code cannot crash, since your code is not well-typed and thus cannot compile. `Random.self_init` initialize the seed of the PRNG. You should call it once in your program, and not at every calls of `randlist`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `match` as if it is going to compare two integer values, but that's not how it works. This match:

```
Match List.length acc with
| dolz -> ...
```

Will always match the first case. The name `dolz` is a new variable that is bound to the length of the list. The outer definition of `dolz` is not relevant here, a pattern introduces *new* names.

If you want to compare two integer values, you should use `if`:

```
if List.length acc = dolz then
    ...
else
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to accomplish can be implemented without having to calculate the length of the accumulated list. You just need to count the length parameter down by one on each iteration and return `acc` when it is less than or equal to `0`.

```
let randlist count max =
  let rec aux c m acc =
    if c <= 0 then acc
    else aux (c-1) m (Random.init max :: acc)
  in
  aux count max []
```

Of course, all of this is just a convoluted way to write:

```
let randlist count max =
  List.init count (fun _ -> Random.int max)
```

Here the `List.init` function takes care of the iteration for us.  Implementing an equivalent function may shed some light on how it works.

```
let list_init n f =
  let rec list_init' n f acc = 
    if n <= 0 then acc 
    else list_init' (n-1) f (f (n-1) :: acc)
  in
  list_init' n f []
```

Or utilizing [`tail_mod_cons`](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/tail_mod_cons.html) to avoid having to using an auxiliary function that has an explicit accumulator:

```
let[@tail_mod_cons] list_init n f =
  if n <= 0 then []
  else 
    let r = f n in
    r :: list_init f (n - 1)
```

Which is very similar to the way `List.init` is actually [implemented](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/list.ml).

> ```
> let[@tail_mod_cons] rec init i last f =
>   if i > last then []
>   else if i = last then [f i]
>   else
>     let r1 = f i in
>     let r2 = f (i+1) in
>     r1 :: r2 :: init (i+2) last f
>
> let init len f =
>   if len < 0 then invalid_arg "List.init" else
>   init 0 (len - 1) f
> ```